# Send SMS to mobile using Java using OzekiNe HTTP Request

Tags: jakarta-ee

#### I'm trying to send SMS to mobile using Java using OzekiNe HTTP Request

Following is My Code . It have no error  Say 'Ok' in console but No Message is not received . What Happen to My Code ?

```
 public class Java_sms_httprequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String recipient = "0979xxxxxxx"; // Phone Number Of Customer
    String message = "Hello"; // Message you want to send
    String username = "admin"; // User Name of SMS GateWay
    String password = "dynamic"; // Password of SMS GateWay
    // They are need to connect SMS GateWay
    String originator = "0920xxxxx";// Your Phone Number;

    String requestURL = "http://127.0.0.1:9400/api?action=sendmessage&"
            + "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")
            + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
            + "&recipient=" + URLEncoder.encode(recipient, "UTF-8")
            + "&messagetype=SMS:TEXT" + "&messagedata="
            + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8") + "&originator"
            + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")
            + "&serviceprovider=HTTPServer0" + "&responseformat=html";

    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    System.out.println(uc.getResponseMessage());

    uc.disconnect();

}
```